# How to install mod_wsgi into Apache on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Other similar answers are out of date or focus on a particular error and not the whole process.

What is the full installation process of mod_wsgi into an Apache installation on Windows 10?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
2. Point `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` to your installation (default is `C:/Apache24`). Use forward slashes:

   ```
   set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:/Users/me/apache
   ```

   For PowerShell this would be (with backward slashes):

   ```
   $env:MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR="C:\Users\me\apache"
   ```
3. Install *mod-wsgi* package:

   ```
   pip install mod-wsgi
   ```

   **Note:** Make sure that the python version you're using has the same architecture (32/64 bit) as your Apache version.
4. Get module configuration:

   ```
   mod_wsgi-express module-config
   ```
5. Copy the output of the previous command into your Apache's `httpd.conf`.

When you restart Apache, mod_wsgi will be loaded. Check out the [quickstart Hello World](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#the-first-wsgi-application) example to test your mod_wsgi installation.

Comment: When I was using Powershell with a virtual environment activated, the command in step 2 did not work for me.  It generated no error but the environment variable did not get set either.  However I got the variable assignment to work using this command instead:  $env:MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR="C:\Users\me\apache".  (Note with this command it needed backward slashes.)  With that substitution for Step 2, the mod-wsgi install in Step 3 was successful.

Comment: I'll add the PowerShel variant

Answer (score 2):

Also be sure to check that your Apache and Python got same architecture (32/64bit) and MS Build Tools is compatible with Python version.

Been trying to compile mod_wsgi using different combinations of MS Build Tools for a few hours before I noticed that Python 3.8 is 32bit and Apache Lounge 2.4 is 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add to @Robin ([Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016004/robin-de-schepper)). This solution is as written by [Graham Dumpleton's answer](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/685#issuecomment-855196201)  in github issues.

Try and delete mod-wsgi first

```
pip uninstall mod_wsgi
```

it will spit out the dir of all the installed mod-wsgi and mod-wsgi-express

```
cd " to the dir mod-express is installed"
```

and then run

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

you will get the config you wanted