# how to get uwsgi on windows

Tags: python, pip

i used the command `pip install uWSGI` but then i get the error

```
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.17.1.tar.gz (800 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Oscar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-39mpiaq2\\uwsgi_c49548e783724e34b0711a03b318a590\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Oscar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-39mpiaq2\\uwsgi_c49548e783724e34b0711a03b318a590\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3lzq9ewp'
         cwd: C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-39mpiaq2\uwsgi_c49548e783724e34b0711a03b318a590\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-39mpiaq2\uwsgi_c49548e783724e34b0711a03b318a590\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import uwsgiconfig as uc
      File "C:\Users\Oscar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-39mpiaq2\uwsgi_c49548e783724e34b0711a03b318a590\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
        uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
    AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/c9/a2d5737f63cd9df4317a4acc15d1ddf4952e28398601d8d7d706c16381e0/uwsgi-2.0.17.1.tar.gz#sha256=d2318235c74665a60021a4fc7770e9c2756f9fc07de7b8c22805efe85b5ab277 (from https://pypi.org/simple/uwsgi/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.17.tar.gz (798 kB)
```

does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gunicorn also does not support Windows. See https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524

If you use Apche server, you can use mod_wsgi. See [How to install mod_wsgi into Apache on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801387/how-to-install-mod-wsgi-into-apache-on-windows)

Or, using docker can be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

By switching operating systems.

[uWSGI doesn't work on bare Windows.](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SupportedPlatforms.html) (It might work on Cygwin, but that's probably not something you want to pursue.)

Comment: so i can't install on windows unless i get cygwin?

Comment: yes, I use it with cygwin; but cannot run it as service, so a user must be signed in at all times for it to work

Comment: @karna7 But in **cygwin terminal** when i type uwsgi i get `uwsgi: command not found`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have installed python into cygwin and then used pip to install uwsgi there; it will compile it so you need gcc and libraries installed