# Setup python on wamp server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and have setup wamp server and installed python 3.6 in location `C:\Program Files\Python36`

> httpd.conf file

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews +ExecCGI
```

when running this script

index.py

```
print("hello world")
```

> http://localhost/index.py

getting this error :

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
> wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error
> occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
> Any solution, Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20128269/7791036

Comment: @vivekpadia70: i have checked this link, Can you please give me link of mod_wsgi Apache Module for python 3.6 windows 10 64 bit

Comment: You can install using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59801388/7791036