# cannot install mod_wsgi on windows over wampserver 3.3.2 6rbit

Tags: django, windows, wamp, mod-wsgi

I have been trying to install mod_wsgi using pipenv install mod_wsgi on windows machine over a wampserver, but I get this error.

I searched google for info on proceeding getting a Django app hosted over Apache, but couldn't find any information (or a resolution). They all mention to install mod-wsgi using "pip install mod-wsgi", as it is tried and tested, but each time I try it, I get this error below.

Any suggestions to overcome this would be helpful. Thanks.

```
(spolls-JBTzETyl) C:\spolls\polls>pipenv install mod_wsgi
Installing mod_wsgi...
Resolving mod_wsgi...
Added mod-wsgi to Pipfile's [packages] ...
Installation Succeeded
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (d0acbf)...                                               
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting mod-wsgi==5.0.0 (from -r c:\users\ti-main1\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-lo438x_j-requirements\pipenv-itch8i1s-hashed-reqs.txt (line 1))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached mod_wsgi-5.0.0.tar.gz (497 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'      
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Building wheels for collected packages: mod-wsgi
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for mod-wsgi (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for mod-wsgi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py clean for mod-wsgi
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Failed to build mod-wsgi
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [33 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running bdist_wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server    
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server\management
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server\management
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\docs      
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\docs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\images    
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\images
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\mod_wsgi\images
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.    
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src       
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\server
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.58/bin/include -IC:\Users\TI-Main1\.virtualenvs\spolls-JBTzETyl\include -IC:\Python311\include -IC:\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       mod_wsgi.c
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\TI-Main1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pb1qnwvr\mod-wsgi_87de50ebb2064b0e9432a0cb7504e637\src\server\wsgi_apache.h(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'httpd.h': No such file or directory
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not build wheels for mod-wsgi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
ERROR: Couldn't install package: {}
 Package installation failed...
```

I search stackOverflow for possible solutions.

Comment: Take a look here; you most likely need the build tools for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59801387/how-to-install-mod-wsgi-into-apache-on-windows